# Probability of picking a specific element in a list

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that we have a list with $n$ elements (where each element is a number between $1$ and $10$) and that each element is picked independently from the other elements in the list in a uniform random manner.

What would be the probability that the number $10$ is in the list? Would it be $\frac{1}{10} \cdot n$ since we have $n$ elements? I find it quite difficult to relate the probability to the list since we are dealing with $n$ elements so the length of the list is not fixed. A brief explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Try first calculating the probability that the $10$ is not in the list.

Comment: Would it be $\frac{9}{10} \cdot n$?

Comment: $\left(\frac9{10}\right)^n$

Comment: Why is it raised to $n$ and not multiplied by $n$? This is the part I am not understanding

Comment: $\frac{1}{10}\cdot n$ is a calculation that is done but it is a calculation *for a different problem*.  That is the *expected number of 10's in the list*.  Note that when $n>10$ your calculation yields a number greater than $1$ which could not have been a probability.

Comment: For a list of length $2$... letting $A$ be the event that the first number in the list is a ten and $B$ the event that the second number in the list is $10$, the probability of the first or second being $10$ would have been $\Pr(A\cup B)$.  Now... you may have heard somewhere that $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$ however that is incorrect.  That is only true when $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$... The correct statement is that $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$, we needed this extra term to deal with the overlap of the possibilities.  Similar adjustments occur for even more events.

Comment: Cf. [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)

Comment: If $\frac{1}{10}\cdot n$ represents the expected number of $10's$ in the list, and given that $n = 5$, the output will be $\frac{1}{10}\cdot 5 =\frac{1}{2}$. What would the result $0.5$ mean? Would that imply that there are $0$ $10's$ in the list?

Comment: "*What would the result 0.5 mean?*"  It means that if we were to have repeated this experiment *many times* that some of the time we may have gotten zero tens, some of the time we got one ten, some of the time we got several tens., and if we were to look at the amounts of tens we had gotten and average them the average would be $0.5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's true that each number has a 1/10 chance of being 10, you can't say that n numbers have a n/10 chance of having a 10, because that would mean that with 10 numbers, you are guaranteed a 10, which is clearly absurd.

The easiest way to solve this is to calculate the probability that 10 is NOT in the list.

The probability that any element is not 10 is 9/10. Therefore, the probability that all n numbers are not 10 is $(\frac{9}{10}$)^n, so by complementary counting, the probability of at least one 10 is $1$ - $(\frac{9}{10}$)^n.